# Algebraic characterisation of quadrilaterals using angles and edge lengths

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In the following I use $A,B,C,D$ for the vertices and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ for the respective adjacent angles and $a,b,c,d$ for the 'adjacent' (in the sense that $a$ originates from $A$, and so on) edges in a general quadrilateral.

I am searching for a simple algebraic characterisation in form of a set of non-redundant equations ($\mathbf{E}$) for the following specific types of quadrilaterals, namely the *square* ($S$), *rectangle* ($Re$), *parallelogram* ($P$), *rhombus* ($Rh$), *trapez* *$^1$ ($T$) and  *kite* ($K$) in such a way that the defintion of all of these can be obtained by simply excluding some of the full set of equations which are given for the $S$.

What I am seeking differs from 'the common way'. For example in using $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=\pi/2$ for the square there is no way to 'lower the symmetry' to say a parallelogram by just dropping these but at the same time without introducing new equations.

I found a way to do this for all $S,Re,P,Rh,T$ except $K$. This works like the following:

$\mathbf{E}=\{$I, II, III, IV, V$\}$ with

$$\begin{align} \alpha+\beta=\pi  \tag{I} \\ \alpha+\gamma=\pi  \tag{II} \\ \alpha+\delta=\pi \tag{III}\\ \beta+\gamma=\pi \tag{IV} \\a=b \tag{V} \end{align}$$

With that $S$ is characterized by $\mathbf{E}$ (the whole set of equations I-V exactly define the square).

$R$ is defined by $\mathbf{E}\setminus \{V\}$, $Rh$ is $\mathbf{E}\setminus \{II\}$, $P$ is $\mathbf{E}\setminus \{II,V\}$ and $T$ is $\mathbf{E}\setminus \{II,III,IV,V\}$. That looks all very nice, the problem here as mentioned above is $K$, for $K$ we need exactly the condition that one pair of opposite angles is equal ($\alpha=\gamma$) which cannot be expressed by simply removing some equations from $\mathbf{E}$. However I have found that the constraint for a kite could be encoded for example like

$$\begin{align} \frac{\beta + \delta}{2} + \alpha = \pi  \tag{Ia} \\  
\frac{\beta + \delta}{2} + \gamma = \pi \tag{IIa} \end{align}$$

which looks somewhat similar to those in $\mathbf{E}$. So now it would be necessary to kind of 'project out' Ia and IIa from $\mathbf{E}$ and then include those into the new equations, but here I get somehow stuck. Can anyone help here?

($\mathbf{E}\setminus \{I,III,IV,V\}$ gives by the way a (general) [cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral)).

---

$^1$) to avoid language confusion I call the quadrilateral with two sides parallel  a *trapez* *

**Additional comment**

I have found meanwhile another way to do the job similarly, but without restricting to conditions on purely angles and edge lengths, ***as pointed out in  the title***. For example one can use the intersection of the diagonals very elegantly to characterise the quadrilaterals by an array of three ratios and an angle, but that would be a different story.

Comment: I came up with these: $$\begin{align}
A+D &=\pi \quad(a\parallel c) \\
A+C &=\pi \quad(\text{cyclic}) \\
a&=c \\
a&=b \\
c&=d
\end{align}$$
They cover all the quadrilateral types. However, since the last three alone characterize a rhombus, which in turn implies the parallelism condition, the set would seem to violate the non-redundancy condition. Hmmmm ...

Comment: @Blue: What do your capital letters ($A,C,D$) mean? Maybe the angles?

Comment: Yes, $A$, $C$, $D$ are angles.